# Bootstrap 4-3 Column Layout Blog positioned horizontially

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Working on a bootstrap 4 layout for a blog project. It'll have 3 columns, but they're positioned in their normal state-stacked onto of each other-not side by side as they should be. I was wondering if you can help me find the problem with my code as I seem to be overlooking something. Thanks for your time.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blog Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blog.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <!---navigation-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Blog</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Resources</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<!--end nav-->
<!--main heading-->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Alice in Wonderland</h1>
    </div>
    <!--/main-heading-->

<!--blog-content-->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-2-md offset-md-1">

</div>

    <div class="col-6-md" id="col1">
      <h2>Heading 1</h2>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
         Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6-md" id="col2">
      <h4>Popular Posts</h4>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
         Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Bootstrap uses a 12 column grid system, `.col-*-2` + `.col-*-6` + `.col-*-6` = 14.

**2.** Your screen/viewport size. It is "smaller" than the `.col-md-*` media query breakpoint. That is why your column's are stacked.

If you really would like the columns structure to persist at other screen/viewport sizes - add corresponding bootstrap classes. `.col-xs-*`, `.col-sm-*`,  `.col-lg-*`,  `.col-xl-*`.